# Java NoSuchElementException in guessing the number

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program for class where the user guesses a number one to ten (the number is set to 6 initially and not random).

However, I am having trouble submitting my code, as Java compiler spits out this error: `java.util.NoSuchElementException on line 29`. Whenever I run the program it works just fine, but the code checker my teacher uses gives me this which is not allowing me to submit the assignment.

If someone could give me some information on the error and how to fix that would be great :)

It's also worth noting that I must use the loop in the code (assignment requires it)

Here is my code so Far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessTheNumber
{ 
    // This is the secret number that will pass the autograder!
    static int secretNumber = 6;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10.");
        System.out.println("See if you can guess the number!");
        
        System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
        int num = input.nextInt();
         
        guessMyNumber(num);
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        
    }
    
    public static void guessMyNumber(int number) 
    {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = number;
        
        while(number != secretNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
            System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: I don't see it in your example, but do you ever close a scanner? If you close a scanner that is built on System.in, it also closes System.in which cannot be reopened, and the next time you use such a scanner, you'll get a NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compare **num** and not **number**.

You are **reasining** the variable **num** but you are **comparing** the formal parameter **number**.

```
public static void guessMyNumber(int number) 
{  
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = number;
    // EDITED HERE 
    while(num != secretNumber)
    {
        System.out.println("Try again!");
        System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
        num = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Probably this is the reason for your **ERROR**.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are comparing `number` with `secrectNumber`, so it should be:

```
    // This is the secret number that will pass the autograder!
    static int secretNumber = 6;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10.");
        System.out.println("See if you can guess the number!");
        
        System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
        int num = input.nextInt();
         
        guessMyNumber(num);
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        
    }
    
    public static void guessMyNumber(int number) 
    {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = number;
        
        while(num != secretNumber)//num not number
        {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
            System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

I think the input only has a limited number, so whenever you pass num into the function, and it's not your secret number, it's going to loop forever and try to read input that doesn't exist(Since there are no more elements to read).